# Can't create database when using string type primary key

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I create Entity class for spring boot project

```
package com.example.pharmanic.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "Rdhs_Driver")
public class Rdhs_Driver {
    @Id
    private String nic;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String address;
    private String telephone;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "reg_no", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "reg_no")
    private Rdhs rdhs;


    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Rdhs_Driver{" +
                "nic=" + nic +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", telephone='" + telephone + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +

                '}';
    }
}
```

But when i run this project, haven't create table. 
But i use 'Long nic' instead of 'String nic', when i change like this tables is created. but i want to use string type primary key.

How I solve this matter ?

Answer (score 0):

Use column annotation like below by putting nullable False.

```
@Id
@Column(name = "NIC", nullable = false)
private String nic;
```